# How to parse a nested json in angular

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have a complex nested json and I want to parse and display the data in html.

My json looks like:

```
{
  "Test Data": [
    {
      "First Test": {
        "Design Name": "testname",
        "Output": "1",
        "Data Info": [
          {
            "Test Name": "ft",
            "Time": 10,
          }
         ]

      }
    },

    {
      "First Test": {
        "Design Name": "testname2",
        "Output": "1",
        "Data Info": [
          {
            "Test Name": "ft2",
            "Time": 10,
          }
         ]

      }
    },
  ]
}
```

This is a subset of my json. How to parse this data and get the array of Design Names

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: One suggestion would be to use Datatables, though there are tons of libraries to achieve what you desire.

Comment: are you trying to show the data in HTML, where you have to loop over the array of this complex JSON, I would suggest you use "Paste JSON As Code" extension of VSCode If you use VS Code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 4):

This is valid JSON so you can use `JSON.parse()` method. And then you can use `map` method to iterate over and get design names like following:

```
let myData = JSON.parse(response); // response is the JSON that you provided

let designNames = myData['Test Data'].map(data => data['"First Test"']['Design Name']);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If your JSON keys does not have spaces:

```
{
    "rootElement": {
        "firstElem": "Some data",
        "secondElem": {
            "thirdLevelElem": "Yet some other data"
        }
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```
const myJsonData = JSON.parse(response);

let firstElement = myJsonData?.rootElement?.firstElem;
let nestdElement = myJsonData?.rootElement?.secondElem?.thirdLevelElem;
```

Answer (score 1):

DEMO

```js
let myData = {
  "Test Data": [
    {
      "First Test": {
        "Design Name": "testname",
        "Output": "1",
        "Data Info": [
          {
            "Test Name": "ft",
            "Time": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "First Test": {
        "Design Name": "testname2",
        "Output": "1",
        "Data Info": [
          {
            "Test Name": "ft2",
            "Time": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

var result =  myData['Test Data'].map(data => data["First Test"]['Design Name']);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same complex nested json too and I want to parse and display the data in html.

My json looks like:

```
{
    "text": "Apple",
    "userName": "Alex",
    "dtoList": [
      {
        "text": "Banana",
        "userName": "Sam",
        "dtoList": [
          {
            "text": "Mango",
            "userName": "Alex",
            "dtoList": [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        "text": "Kiwi",
        "userName": "Clover",
        "dtoList": [
          {
           "text": "Carrots",
            "userName": "Alex",
            "dtoList": [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        "text": "Beef",
        "userName": "Adam",
        "dtoList": [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "text": "Egg",
    "userName": "Adam",
    dtoList: [
      {
        "text": "Broccoli",
        "userName": "Alex",
        "dtoList": [],
      },
      {
        "text": "Pumpkin",
        "userName": "Sam",
        "dtoList": [
          {
            "text": "Brussels sprouts",
            "userName": "Adam",
            "dtoList": [],
          },
          {
            "text": "Fruit loops",
            "userName": "Clover",
            "dtoList": [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

How to parse this data in angular T_T

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31220247)

Comment: Thank you for replying me. I have a question like that in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354474/cant-bind-data-from-spring-boot-to-angular-with-treeview-data) **bold** here