# Can't bind data from spring-boot to Angular with Treeview data

Tags: angular, frontend, treeview

**The idea**

I want to create an comment of the post. The comment can be nested each other like Reddit.com or Facebook [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmVGJ.png) By using

Here is my example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtzh5a?file=src/app/tree-flat-overview-example.html

But when i implement data from backend. Data row like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 63,
        "postId": 16,
        "createdDate": 1581613200.000000000,
        "text": "1",
        "userName": "cuongnga",
        "parent": 0,
        "level": 1,
        "dtoList": [
            {
                "id": 65,
                "postId": 16,
                "createdDate": 1581613200.000000000,
                "text": "3",
                "userName": "cuongnga",
                "parent": 63,
                "level": 2,
                "dtoList": []
            },
            {
                "id": 67,
                "postId": 16,
                "createdDate": 1581613200.000000000,
                "text": "5",
                "userName": "cuongnga",
                "parent": 63,
                "level": 2,
                "dtoList": []
            },
            {
                "id": 68,
                "postId": 16,
                "createdDate": 1645282033.274324000,
                "text": "6",
                "userName": "admin12344",
                "parent": 63,
                "level": 2,
                "dtoList": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 64,
        "postId": 16,
        "createdDate": 1581613200.000000000,
        "text": "2",
        "userName": "cuongnga",
        "parent": 0,
        "level": 1,
        "dtoList": [
            {
                "id": 66,
                "postId": 16,
                "createdDate": 1581613200.000000000,
                "text": "4",
                "userName": "cuongnga",
                "parent": 64,
                "level": 2,
                "dtoList": []
            },
            {
                "id": 69,
                "postId": 16,
                "createdDate": 1645282072.131938000,
                "text": "7",
                "userName": "admin12344",
                "parent": 64,
                "level": 2,
                "dtoList": []
            },
            {
                "id": 70,
                "postId": 16,
                "createdDate": 1645282076.143212000,
                "text": "8",
                "userName": "admin12344",
                "parent": 64,
                "level": 2,
                "dtoList": [
                    {
                        "id": 71,
                        "postId": 16,
                        "createdDate": 1645282328.834463000,
                        "text": "9",
                        "userName": "admin12344",
                        "parent": 70,
                        "level": 2,
                        "dtoList": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 72,
                        "postId": 16,
                        "createdDate": 1645282398.386108000,
                        "text": "10",
                        "userName": "admin12344",
                        "parent": 70,
                        "level": 3,
                        "dtoList": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my code in Angular component: ViewPostComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from 'src/app/shared/post.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PostModel } from 'src/app/shared/post-model';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommentPayload } from 'src/app/comment/comment.payload';
import { CommentService } from 'src/app/comment/comment.service';
import { FlatTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatTreeFlatDataSource, MatTreeFlattener } from '@angular/material/tree';
interface ExampleFlatNode {
  expandable: boolean;
  userName: string;
  text: string;
  level: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-post',
  templateUrl: './view-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-post.component.css']
})
export class ViewPostComponent implements OnInit {

  postId: number;
  post: PostModel;
  commentForm: FormGroup;
  commentPayload: CommentPayload;
  comments: CommentPayload[];

  constructor(private postService: PostService, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private commentService: CommentService, private router: Router) {
    this.postId = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params.id;

    this.commentForm = new FormGroup({
      text: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
    this.commentPayload = {
      text: '',
      postId: this.postId
    };
    this.dataSource.data = this.comments;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPostById();
    this.getCommentsForPost();
  }

  postComment() {
    this.commentPayload.text = this.commentForm.get('text').value;
    this.commentService.postComment(this.commentPayload).subscribe(data => {
      this.commentForm.get('text').setValue('');
      this.getCommentsForPost();
    }, error => {
      throwError(error);
    })
  }

  private getPostById() {
    this.postService.getPost(this.postId).subscribe(data => {
      this.post = data;
    }, error => {
      throwError(error);
    });
  }

  private getCommentsForPost() {
    this.commentService.getAllCommentsForPost(this.postId).subscribe(data => {
      this.comments = data;
    }, error => {
      throwError(error);
    });
  }

private _transformer = (node: CommentPayload, level: number) => {
  return {
    expandable: !!node.dtoList && node.dtoList.length > 0,
    userName: node.username,
    text: node.text,
    level: level,
  };
};

treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<ExampleFlatNode>(
  (node) => node.level,
  (node) => node.expandable
);

treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
  this._transformer,
  (node) => node.level,
  (node) => node.expandable,
  (node) => node.dtoList
);

dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);


hasChild = (_: number, node: ExampleFlatNode) => node.expandable;
}
```

CommentPayload.ts and PostModel

```
export class CommentPayload{
    text: string;
    postId: number;
    username?:string;
    duration?: string;
    dtoList?:CommentPayload[];
}
export class PostModel {
    id: number;
    postName: string;
    url: string;
    description: string;
    voteCount: number;
    userName: string;
    subredditName: string;
    commentCount: number;
    duration: string;
    upVote: boolean;
    downVote: boolean;
}
```

And View-PostComponent

```
 <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
      <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
      <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
        <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
        <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
        {{node.userName + node.text}}
      </mat-tree-node>
      <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
      <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
        <button
          mat-icon-button
          matTreeNodeToggle
          [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.userName   + 'node.text'"
        >
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <p>{{node.userName}}</p>
        <b>{{node.text}}</b>
      </mat-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
```

And it isn't work. The tree isn' made show up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diF4T.png)

**In conclusion**. My example at stackblitz is fine but When i deploy to my project, getting data from back-end and it's not working.
So i need an advise or suggest. I don't know what im wrong T_T